# Ajax + jQuery post url with Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new with AJAX and jQuery and I'm trying to post a new comment to `'campground/campground_.id'` with my `ajax.js` file, but I couldn't find out how to write the URL with Id...
I've tryed:

```
 $('#new-comment-form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var comment = $(this).serialize();
     $.post('/campgrounds/' + campground._id, comment, function(data){
         debugger;
     });
 })
```

**error campground not defined**

```
$('#new-comment-form').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var comment = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('/campgrounds/campground._id', comment, function(data){
        debugger;
    });
})
```

**error POST not found**

```
$('#new-comment-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment = $(this).serialize();

    $.post('/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>', comment, function(data){
        debugger;
    });
})
```

**error Bad request**

Can someone help me how to write it properly?

Comment: where do you get the id from?

Comment: `'/campgrounds/' + campground._id` should work, assuming the `campground` object is properly defined and has the `_id` property on it.  Right before the `$.post` insert `console.log(campground) and tell us what it says in the console.

Comment: This depends on what `campground._id` really is? Is it a variable, part of the URL, something coming from the serverside through a templating language ?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear on my question the Id is part of the URL... Each campground has it's own randomly created Id, and I want to use it as the URL on the post round. The complete URL is https://candy-marimattana.c9users.io/campgrounds/595a956e4c4cf513d5c512d7 but this Id, by the end, is different for each one.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the server page that handle the request , if you rre using  local server  just put nmae of the file , or if a remote server put the compltet url